# Is not this guy using a flightcontroller?

Tags: gyroscope, flight-controller

I know this will not be a good way of asking something but I cannot think a better way.

In this video : https://youtu.be/wg8ZbiC9IBw

He builds a fixed wing an makes it fly, my question is related to the things happening **between minutes 3 and 4**;

I think he must be using a flight controller so that, as it can be seen in the beginning of 3rd minute, the airplane flies nice, but then he says that

> I put that 3-axis gyro so that it can fly more stable

I am confused at that point, doesn't a flightcontroller has its own gyroscope already? What is the need of the external one?

Answer (score 0):

Not all flight controllers are equal. There may be some without built in gyroscopes.

We dont know which controller the guy used, so its difficult to know why he has an external gyro....he may also have just not know the controller he bought has one built it...or it was junk.

> For example, the ICM20602 on the Raceflight Revolt V2, or the ICM20689 on the Kakute F4, both can run at 32KHz. However it’s reported that these IMU are more susceptible to noise than the older MPU6000 therefore these FC’s generally require soft-mounting and filtering capacitors to reduce the amount of noise getting to the Gryo.

Comment: How can a FC stabilize an aircraft without using a gyro?

Comment: a properly designed airplane does not require a gyro to be stable .... think of paper airplanes

Comment: @jsotola then, does that imply a properly designed airplane without any ingoing stabilization control system, can also be stable? Or short, Is only having control over the 3 control surfaces enough to make such a thing fly? Or maybe another way to ask, not having a complex flight controller and using only a microcontroller to communicate so that it drives the motor(s) according to your rc transmitter signals, would that work?

Comment: people have been flying model airplanes for many decades before flight controllers became available .... all you need is a remote control and a little bit of practice with the remote control

Comment: @jsotola or a clockwork timer to turn the rudder so it comes back to you after a few minutes

Comment: @PeteKirkham, or run after it ... lol ... we used to get the plane into the air using a string like a kite ... the string had a metal ring on the end and the plane has a hook